# Simultaneous Version Numbering

Tags: project-management, versioning

This question mixes a bit of project management as well as development. I understand the [major].[minor].[patch] scheming for version numbering of a project. With my clients' projects I use these numbering primarily for internal purposes so instead of refering to a project by the features involved, the team can say "what is the progress of v1.3.2?".

However, sometimes our clients have multiple minor releases at once. Each minor release contains a set of independent features (working with different departments of the client company), but both could launch different times. So if we label them as v1.3.3 and v1.3.4, the v1.3.4 version could release earlier than v1.3.3 and then the whole naming scheme is invalid.

How do you refer internally to these various builds if you don't know which will release first (due to waiting for client approval, or other external scheduling conflicts)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple -- we don't assign version numbers until we release. Problem solved!

That may sound flippant, but it's the truth. Sure, we would have internal projects dubbed e.g. "v5.5", but those were separate and independent from current work on the next iteration of v5.4.x, which would receive the next value of 'x' only upon completion and release. When v5.5 is ready, work on 5.4 ceases, we merge any changes made to 5.4 into 5.5, and then we release 5.5.0.

If you have separate builds for different clients (departments in your case), you can employ a modified versioning scheme. What we did is use [major].[minor].[client].[patch], e.g. 5.4.client1.4. The [patch] would be independent and only meaningful to that particular client, whereas [major].[minor] would correspond to the [major].[minor] version of the main codebase from which we forked off. For example, we might have simultaneous work on 5.5, 5.4.x, and 5.4.client1.x. When 5.5 is ready, 5.4.x merges into that, and then both projects fold into 5.5.x, but the client project might not be ready to merge all those changes and thus it would remain 5.4.client1.x until it was brought up-to-date with 5.5, then becoming 5.5.client1.x.

This may sound confusing, but it actually worked very well for us. We previously employed a variation of this scheme, where the client name was appended to the complete version number, i.e. [major].[minor].[patch]_[client]; again, however, [major].[minor] corresponds to the "core" [major].[minor] from whence it was forked/last merged, and the [patch] is wholly independent from the other versions and only meaningful to that client (this is why we later swapped the relative positions of [client] and [patch], to make it clear that e.g. 5.4.7 might actually have more fixes/be more "current" than 5.4.12.client1, and to better communicate that independence.

When a client-specific project merges back, of course, you drop it and increment to the next [patch], or perhaps make the jump up to the next [minor] or even [major] version, depending on the nature of the work. This does occasionally lead to some temporary confusion when a client project merges into the 5.4.x project and then we release from that version 6.0, then remember to rename the internal 5.5 project to 6.1, but it worked nonetheless.

As an alternative for your environment, internally refer to your current projects simply by client (department) name, e.g. the Accounting project, the HR project, etc. Don't use version numbers internally for this kind of thing, because as you see it just leads to confusion like version 5.4.6 coming out after 5.4.7 but before 5.4.9; meanwhile 5.4.8 never gets released because it was canceled. That's just a mess, so stay away from that. Simply call your projects by client name, and assign the next number